# Parsing a buffer in C

Tags: c, parsing, buffer

This is a C question about parsing through a buffer. I have a buffer `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]` that looks something like this: `b'\x01\x02\x00\x04\x00\x04aaaabbbb'` Basically I want to parse them out into other values like:

```
1 > arg1;
2 > arg2;
4 > text1_length;
4 > text2_length; 
97,97,97,97 > text1 = "aaaa"
98,98,98,98 > text2 = "bbbb"
```

I've tried stuff like using memcpy, but it gets tricky when trying to get the bytes into a char*:

```c
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // b'\x01\x02\x00\x04\x00\x04aaaabbbb'

uint8_t arg1 = buffer[0];
uint8_t arg2 = buffer[1];
uint16_t text1_length = (uint16_t) buffer[2];
uint16_t text2_length = (uint16_t) buffer[4];

char* text1 = malloc(text1_length + 1);
char* text2 = malloc(text2_length + 1);

memcpy(text1, &buffer[6], (size_t) text1_length);
memcpy(text2, &buffer[6+text1_length], (size+t) text2_length);
```

Trying to print out any of the lengths just shows 0's right now and I'm guessing its because the first byte of the 2 bytes is a 0.

Comment: Does the buffer contain data in little endian or big endian order? This is particularly important in order to parse `uint16_t`.

Comment: Never mind, it seems like only one byte will be placed inside `text1_length` and `text2_length`, so they're practically of type `uint8_t`.

Comment: @OP I'll update my answer according to your last edit.

Comment: `b'\x01\x02\x00\x04\x00\x04aaaabbbb'` -> This is the actual buffer. It's being sent across a network so I'm receiving it into a `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]`

Comment: @TF Does my updated answer work?

Comment: `b'\x01\x02\x00\x04\x00\x04aaaabbbb'` is not a valid ISO C character constant. You seem to be using compiler-specific extensions. Or is that supposed to be the content of a string? Please show us exactly how you are defining the contents of `buffer`. For the purpose of having a clear question, it should be possible for you to define the contents of `buffer` yourself, using ISO C syntax, instead of simply saying that you are receiving the contents from a network.

Comment: @LucaPolito that worked - it's not the prettiest, but it works

@AndreasWenzel the c server command `recv(sockfd, receive_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0)` is used to fill the buffer and the python client command to send it is `self.sock.sendall(message)` where `message=b'\x01\x02\x00\x04\x00\x04aaaabbbb'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```c
uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

uint8_t arg1 = buffer[0];
uint8_t arg2 = buffer[1];
uint16_t text1_length = ((uint16_t) buffer[2] << 8) + (uint16_t) buffer[3];
uint16_t text2_length = ((uint16_t) buffer[4] << 8) + (uint16_t) buffer[5];

char* text1 = malloc(text1_length + 1); // TODO: check for NULL
char* text2 = malloc(text2_length + 1); // TODO: check for NULL

memcpy(text1, &buffer[6], (size_t) text1_length);
text1[text1_length] = '\0';

memcpy(text2, &buffer[6 + text1_length], (size_t) text2_length);
text2[text2_length] = '\0';

// TODO: free() both text1 and text2
```

EDIT: code has been updated, based on your last edit.

Comment: The buffer contains data in big endian order (it was packed using a python client `struct.pack('>BBHH', arg1, arg2, text1_length, text2_length) + (text1 + text2).encode()`. I'm going to edit the original question to more closely reflect what I'm trying to do. When I tried the above it caused the length for text1 and text2 to be 0 and therefore missed out of doing anything that comes after setting memory for text1 and text2

Comment: @TF Oh, so the buffer *does* contain integers of type `uint16_t`, doesn't it? Update the question and I'll update my answer.